# Find User role in context.Users without Identity Managers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, identity

I'm working on a `WebApi` project.

I have `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And `context` with his interface:

```
public interface ITaskManagerDbContext
{
    DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

//class

public class TaskManagerDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ITaskManagerDbContext
{
    public TaskManagerDbContext(DbContextOptions<TaskManagerDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(TaskManagerDbContext).Assembly);
    }
}
```

I want to find user. I'm doing it by this line of code:

```
var user = await this.context.Users.FindAsync(request.ApplicationUserId);
```

My question is, how to find `Role` attached to user in my `context`? I don't want to use `UserManager` or `RoleManager` from `Identity`. Is it possible to find user's roles in `context`?

Comment: Silly question, why would you **not** want to use classes that do all the work for you?

Comment: The context is a normal EF Context. As far as I know there is nothing stopping you from getting the DbSet with the user roles and querying it yourself. But I don't see the point of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only stumbling block really is that `User`, itself, doesn't have something like a `Roles` collection on it. However, you can access `UserRole` from the context directly and query based on the user:

```
var roleIds = await _context.UserRoles
    .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)
    .Select(x => x.RoleId)
    .ToListAsync();

var roles = await _context.Roles
    .Where(x => roleIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Yes, this requires two additional queries, but it gets the job done. The more efficient way, of course, is to just use `UserManager<TUser>.GetRolesAsync`.